# Any example of the US being involved in a civil war of another country that the USA recognizes as a sovereign state?

Tags: united-states, civil-war

Are there any examples from the 20th and 21st century of the US being military involved (perhaps, only in the way of sending its avation) in some civil war in any country that it recognizes as a sovereign state?

Comment: There are easily scores of examples: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_proxy_wars

Comment: Uh… Cuba in its revolution against Spain, several Latin American states, the Philippines, Libya, Syria, Kosovo in Yugoslavia, (technically speaking) Somalia…  This question doesn't need an answer, it needs a reference text.

Comment: @TedWrigley -Did the US recognize the sovereignty of Yugoslavia when it bombed it?

Comment: @TedWrigley: *Cuba in its revolution against Spain,* -- that's 19th C though.

Comment: @brilliant was there any time when the US didn't recognize the sovereignty of Yugoslavia?

Comment: @phoog - That's my very question that I am asking (in the comments).

Comment: @brilliant There was a time before it officially changed its name to "Serbia and Montenegro" that they were calling it that because they didn't recognize its claim to be the sole successor state of the larger Yugoslavia. But they recognized its sovereignty.

Comment: @phoog - You mean they recognized the sovereingty of what they reffered to as "Serbia and Montenegro"?

Comment: Yes.  But they held that the other former Yugoslav states were also successor states of the state that had existed from 1918 to 1992, whereas the government in Belgrade denied the claims of the other states.

Comment: @user103496: Ah, well, I thought it ended in 1902, but it apparently ended in 1898. C'est la vie!

Comment: I'd guess the OP is confused what "[recognizing something as a sovereign state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sovereign_state)" entails. It's a fairly low bar, and is not the same as recognising the government as legitimate or having diplomatic relations; it's often implicit, and just involves treating something as if it were a sovereign state, rather than denying it's a sovereign state. It might involve having an embassy or other diplomatic contact, making a formal pronouncement, or accepting UN membership. Even a declaration of war is arguably recognising something as a foreign state.

Comment: @StuartF - May I know what you mean by a "fairly low bar"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a lot of examples. Afghanistan was mentioned already, some more:

Europe:

Russia - 1918: The US were part of the [Allied intervention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allied_intervention_in_the_Russian_Civil_War#Foreign_forces_throughout_Russia) in the Russian civil war following the Bolshevik revolution.

Middle East - a lot of examples. Some of the more recent:

Syria - 2014: The [US stepped in](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/US_intervention_in_the_Syrian_civil_war) to push back against ISIS which was trying to topple the Syrian government.

Libya - 2014: Similarly, the [US was attacking ISIS forces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libyan_civil_war_(2014%E2%80%932020)) in Libya, backing the National Government forces.

Lebanon - 1980s: The US was part of the [multinational force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinational_Force_in_Lebanon#Barracks_bombing) intervening in the civil war there. The most well-known event of that time is the marines barracks bombing.

Americas:

Chile - 1970s: [The US has been involved](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_intervention_in_Chile) in the Chilean civil war, and the CIA was actively involved in the overthrowing of the Allende government.

There are a whole lot more examples.

Comment: Korea and Vietnam also fit the bill, if one pushes slightly the meaning  of "civil war". Both Koreas still claim the whole peninsula. And surely North Vietnam claimed the South (can't be bothered to check if there was a claim in the opposite direction.) Yeah, US intervention in Korea was under the UN flag, because the USSR was stupid to let that happen--a mistake they've not repeated since then.

Comment: "ISIS which was trying to topple the Syrian government". I think the US cared more that ISIS had taken over large parts of Iraq, and they'd have "toppled" that gov't if they could. Intervention in Syria was a corollary to that. The US also "unrecognized" the Asad regime, at one point.

Comment: @Fizz I don't think the US ever unrecognized Syrian sovereignty though.

Comment: True, but if the US directly backed anyone in Syria to the extent that the Q asks, e.g. with air strikes, those were the Kurds/YPG, when engaged with ISIS (but not when Turkey attacked them). It was Russia who backed up Asad with an air force.

Comment: I'm sure there could be books written about each of these events, the question was about involvement.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you somehow have in mind some unusual definitions, this seems an extremely trivial Q to answer, e.g. in Afghanistan there was a civil war between the Taliban and the Karzai government. US and many Western countries backed the latter. Of course the US recognized and recognizes Afghanistan as a sovereign country, in the legal/diplomatic sense of the word. That they may not recognize the Taliban *government* even now as a legitimate one is another matter.

---

I see you ask in a comment:

> Did the US recognize the sovereignty of Yugoslavia when it bombed it?

I suppose your beef is that the US says they recognize some country as sovereign but they don't always [fully] respect that sovereignty, in the sense that the US sometimes initiates military operations on some territory without the approval or even against some gov't.

There are degrees of respecting the sovereignty of a country/government, for sure, as you should probably know since you marked your account as located in Russia, which had its fair share of invading their neighbors, and even formally annexing some of their territory, more recently. The US hasn't done the latter in a long time--some [pacific islands at the end of WW2](https://ballotpedia.org/United_States_territorial_acquisitions). FWTW, that source seems somewhat incorrect in that the US the status of some of those islands is/was [more complicated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trust_Territory_of_the_Pacific_Islands#Current_status).

Comment: The US was also actively involved in the previous Afghan civil war, openly supplying the fighters against the Soviets and the pro-Soviet government (which ironically were the same Taliban the US was fighting later). The US also sent troops to actively fight for the "Whites" in the Russian civil war following the 1917 bolshevik revolution.

Comment: For the OP: BTW, you could look e.g. at [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.polgeo.2010.01.005) that discusses empirical approaches/measures to/of sovereignty (in contrast with much of the legalistic/theoretical literature that emphasizes its absoluteness.)

Comment: @littleadv: "ironically were the same Taliban". Some of them were. The mujahedeen then split up and fought among each other. They were actually still fighting each other when the US intervened to oust the Taliban after 9/11. The Taliban controlled most of Afghanistan then, but not all of it. The "Northern Alliance" (which was still holding some portions of Afghanistan, and was fighting the Taliban) was also comprised of mujahedeen that the US had supported in the war against the Soviets.

Comment: @Fizz - Thanks for the paper!